# Coding Challenge, trying to solve recursively. help on caching using Closure

Tags: javascript, recursion, closures

the question:
/ A step(x) operation works like this: it changes a number x into x - s(x), where s(x) is the sum of x's digits. 
//You like applying functions to numbers, so given the number n, you decide to build a decreasing sequence of numbers: n, step(n), 
//step(step(n)), etc., with 0 as the last element.

// Building a single sequence isn't enough for you, so you replace all elements of the sequence with the sums of their digits (s(x)). 
//Now you're curious as to which number appears in the new sequence most often. If there are several answers, return the maximal one.

// **Example**

// -   For n = 88, the output should be
// mostFrequentDigitSum(n) = 9.

// Here is the first sequence you built: 88, 72, 63, 54, 45, 36, 27, 18, 9, 0;

// And here is s(x) for each of its elements: 16, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0.

// As you can see, the most frequent number in the second sequence is 9.

// -   For n = 8, the output should be
// mostFrequentDigitSum(n) = 8.

// At first you built the following sequence: 8, 0

// s(x) for each of its elements is: 8, 0

// As you can see, the answer is 8 (it appears as often as 0, but is greater than it).

So I looked at this question and it just seemed like recursion would be good here.  I am sure there is a far easier way to do it iteratively but I am also trying to get better at recursion so I tried it out using recursion.

```
let cache = {}

function recursiveCall ( x ) {
    if( x == 0 ) { return 'dog' } // we dont need to return anything, because after each recursive call we are saving cache[sumOfX] in our cache,
    //once we get to the very TOP of our stack when it hit 0.  We have already made our object, and therefore do not even need a return statement.


    //get the sum of our digits for x.
    let sumOfX = x.toString().split('').map( n => { return Number(n)}).reduce( (sum, num) => {
        sum += num;
        return sum;
    },0);

    //creates a key for a sumOfX and makes the value 1 if it hasnt been seen or increments the value if it has been seen.
    if( !cache[sumOfX] ) {
        cache[sumOfX] = 1;
    } else {
        cache[sumOfX]++;
    }



    console.log(x);
    console.log(sumOfX);
    recursiveCall( x - sumOfX );
    console.log(cache)
}



function mostFrequentDigitSum( digit ) {
//create our cache using our recursive call
recursiveCall(digit);

//find the largest value in that object.
let max = 0;
let value = 0;
for(var key in cache) {
    if( max < cache[key]) {
        max = cache[key];
        value = Number(key);
    }
}
return value;
}


console.log(mostFrequentDigitSum(88));

console.log(cache);
```

I created an object using recursion.  I had to make a global variable for my cache though, and I want my code to be self contained.  I tried to do a few things to make it work as a closure but still have not came up with a solution.  Any tips would be helpful, As I am trying to get better at recursion if there is another way to solve this recursively I wouldn't mine taking a look at others people's code.  Making mine work recursively and in a self contained closure would be very helpful too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `recursiveCall` accept a second parameter, `cache`, that defaults to `{}`.

```
function recursiveCall(x, cache = {}) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return cache;
  }
  // ...
  return recursiveCall(x - sumOfX, cache);
}
```

On the first call of `recursiveCall`, the `cache` object will be created; on subsequent recursive calls to `recursiveCall`, you can pass that object as the second parameter. When you reach the end of the recursion, `return cache` so that it gets returned to the initial call:

```
function mostFrequentDigitSum(digit) {
  //create our cache using our recursive call
  const cache = recursiveCall(digit);
```

And then you can use that `cache` variable to calculate the `value` to be returned from `mostFrequentDigitSum`. `cache` is now not global, it's created anew every time `mostFrequentDigitSum` is called (or, to be more precise, every time `recursiveCall` is called externally).

```js
function recursiveCall(x, cache = {}) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return cache;
  }
  //get the sum of our digits for x.
  let sumOfX = x.toString().split('').map(n => {
    return Number(n)
  }).reduce((sum, num) => {
    sum += num;
    return sum;
  }, 0);

  //creates a key for a sumOfX and makes the value 1 if it hasnt been seen or increments the value if it has been seen.
  if (!cache[sumOfX]) {
    cache[sumOfX] = 1;
  } else {
    cache[sumOfX]++;
  }
  return recursiveCall(x - sumOfX, cache);
}



function mostFrequentDigitSum(digit) {
  //create our cache using our recursive call
  const cache = recursiveCall(digit);

  //find the largest value in that object.
  let max = 0;
  let value = 0;
  for (var key in cache) {
    if (max < cache[key]) {
      max = cache[key];
      value = Number(key);
    }
  }
  return value;
}


console.log(mostFrequentDigitSum(88));
```

Or, to trim down your code while keeping the same logic:

```js
function recursiveCall(x, cache = {}) {
  if (x === 0) {
    return cache;
  }
  const sumOfX = x.toString().split('').map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  cache[sumOfX] = (cache[sumOfX] || 0) + 1;
  return recursiveCall(x - sumOfX, cache);
}

function mostFrequentDigitSum(digit) {
  //create our cache using our recursive call
  const cache = recursiveCall(digit);
  //find the largest value in that object.
  return Object.entries(cache).reduce((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? a : b, [null, 0])[0];
}
console.log(mostFrequentDigitSum(88));
console.log(mostFrequentDigitSum(8));
console.log(mostFrequentDigitSum(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is with recursion

```
const objOfFinalSums={}
function solution(n) {
    const numToString = n.toString().split('')
    let sum = numToString.reduce( (accumulator, current_value) => accumulator+=parseInt(current_value),0)
    objOfFinalSums[sum] ? objOfFinalSums[sum]++ : objOfFinalSums[sum] = 1;
    return !sum == 0 ? solution(n-sum) : parseInt(Object.keys(objOfFinalSums).reduce( (accumulator,current_value) => objOfFinalSums[current_value] >= objOfFinalSums[accumulator] ? accumulator=current_value : accumulator, 0))
}
```